# What does this part of the song "Weitergehen" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

***Ich hab noch nicht aufgehört zu träumen, wie der Wind sich auch dreht einfach weitergehen.***

My conjecture for the "wind part" is somethinkg like:

**

> I have not stopped dreaming about moving on ahead, as the tide turns.

**

I don't get what "wie" here means and whether "weitergehen" refers back to the speaker or not. For if it does, I reckon that it must be "weitezugehen" instead.

Answer (score 2):

The infinitive "weitergehen" works as an *impersonal imperative replacement form* here.

This form is typically used as an impersonal form on prohibitive signs, for example:

> Nicht rauchen!
>
> Vorsichtig öffnen!

German knows a number of grammatical constructs to form the imperative and replacements for it - This is one of them. This part would roughly translate to

> ...however the winds are turning, just go on.

Because the imperative replacement is *impersonal*, i.e. not addressed to someone specifically, it has no *grammatical* relationship to the "ich" in the sentence, the connection is only from context. You can interpret it as "Order to self: go on".

Comment: See [this page, about half way down](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Verb/Kategorien/Modi/Imperativ.html) for more information on this particular construction. Another name for it is the 'free infinitive' or *Freier Infinitiv*. Altogether I count six ways to form an imperative other than the ones usually covered in German textbooks.

Comment: @RDBury Note: There is more than one way to form a *semantical* imperative. But actually only one to form a *grammatical* one.

Comment: Good point. I was going through the list after posting that comment and found many of them had parallels in English. There are imperative statements ("I'd like you to ..."), imperative questions ("Would you mind ..."), and I suppose questions that are grammatical imperatives ("Tell me what you think of ...") The impersonal imperative does not have a parallel in English though; the closest I could think of were a few idiomatic phrase "Not to worry," "Not to mention ... ."

Answer (score 2):

The texts of this Tim Bendzko-song I found have a full stop between the two parts:

> Nein, ich hab noch nicht aufgehört zu träumen.
>   Wie der Wind sich auch dreht, einfach weitergehen.

These two lines translate to

> No, I have not stopped dreaming.
>   No matter how the wind turns, just go ahead.

So "wie" means it's no matter from where the wind blows. "Weitergehen" refers to the speaker, as the song is about to never give up. It's a request to the speaker itself not to stop but always go ahead.